# Setting the SelectedItemIndex in a DataGridCombobBoxColumn

Tags: wpf

How do I set the selected item index from code-behind in a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into this example, I couldn't verify if it works but seems to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/31/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboboxcolumn-v1-intro.aspx

Comment: but may be you can also consider that, you bind selecteditem to datagridcombobox and your viewmodel converts seleteditemindex to selecteditem. This way you don't need to traverse in your datagrid rows but in your bound collection (can use linq)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the Row Index and Column Index this should do the trick.

```
DataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value = "1"
```

You can set the value not the index.

Comment: What if I want to select the first item by default?

Comment: If you know the Value then set it.

Comment: I don't know the value. I want to select the FIRST element in the dropdown. Something like SelectedIndex = 0.